# birthday duplicates after removing google account and adding it again

Tags: contacts, calendar, google-account, htc-sense, htc-one-s

After removing my Google-Account on my HTC One S and adding it again, i recognized that all birthdays stored with contacts are in my calendar twice. When i change birthday at some contact, there is only one, which changes. The information is not from another calendar like Facebook or Google.
After removing my account once and adding it, i had two birthdays for each contact, only one changes.
After removing my account another time and adding it, i had three birthdays for each conatct and only one changes.

So why this happens or how can i delete or avoid this?

I would like the delete either automically or manually (prefering automatically) but i found no solution to do this.

I made a screenshot to make it clearer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, the only thing that helped was a softreset.i wanted to do it fast. And after the new HTC Update i switched to some Custom Roms anyway.

Answer (score -1):

"Online version of GCalToolkit" may help.

http://gcaltoolkit.net/

> Follow these simple steps to remove all duplicates from Google
>   Calendar, clean up failed Imports and Sync Sessions, delete events
>   based on text or date ranges, and more... If that's not enough -
>   please try the Windows Desktop Software version of GCalToolkit.:

Comment: I have these duplicates only on my phone, so i don't think that works. It's no Google Calendar Entry.

Comment: In that case you could try to first sync your phone calender with google calender. Then use the provided link. Sync again if required.